# Failed to parse time string (900) at position 0 using DateTimeImmutable

Tags: php, datetime

I am receiving from an external API the dates like 500, 1100, 1400,2100 etc, where 500 is equal to 5am, 1100 is 11am.. etc.

I want to assert that they send me valid values, so I did some phpunit test, with numbers greater tan 1000 I do not have any problem, in the class constructor I do something like this:

```
new \DateTimeImmutable((string) $hour);
if for example, I do new \DateTimeImmutable((string) 1900); and I do a dump, I get something like :
DateTimeImmutable @1653152400 {#411
   date: 2022-05-21 19:00:00.0 Europe/Madrid (+02:00)
}
```

and everything works fine, not the same when using a number lower than 1000, example using 900:

```
Exception : DateTimeImmutable::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (900) at position 0 (9): Unexpected character
```

Comment: Usually those 4 digit numbers are used to signify GMT offsets, isn't there any other format that API provides?

Answer (score 1):

24 hour time notation needs 2 digits for the hours ([See here for valid formats)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php). So you need to prepend a zero for the smaller numbers. For example:

```
$hour = ($hour < 1000 ? '0' : '').$hour;
var_dump(new \DateTimeImmutable($hour));
```